# UltraStar deluxe don't Start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ultrastar-deluxe

I tried to install UltraStar deluxe for Karaoke on my Ubuntu 14.04 HTPC.
The installation was okay but when try to start the Game via Advance Launcher
the system freez. I checked the Error-log of UltraStar deluxe and found the following
massage:

```
UltraStar Deluxe V 1.1.0 Build Error Log
Date: 14-6-14 Time: 00:34:18
ERROR:  libavformat header (54.20.4) and DLL (54.20.3) versions do not match. 
ERROR:  Initialize failed, Removing - SDL_Playback
```

when I tried to start via console I received the following errors

```
xbmc@mediacenter:/usr/games$ ./ultrastardx
An unhandled exception occurred at $000000000044822E :
EAccessViolation : Access violation
  $000000000044822E
  $00000000004D71DC
  $00000000004C9EA6
  $000000000047250B

xbmc@mediacenter:/usr/games$ sudo ./ultrastardx
Home directory not accessible: Keine Berechtigung
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611
Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611
SDL_SetVideoMode Failed [Initialize3D]
```

how can I solve this?